# Can I append data to the buffer while repeating SSL_write()?

Tags: ssl, openssl, nonblocking

The following description is about `int SSL_write(SSL *ssl, const void *buf, int num)`:

> When an SSL_write() operation has to be repeated because of
>   SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE, it must be repeated with
>   **the same arguments**.

What does the word *"same"* mean exactly?  Is it right if I remain the same `buf` pointer while appending data to this buffer?

Answer (score 1):

*same* means `ssl` points to the same `SSL` object, `num` is the same value as before, `buf` points to the same buffer, and the first `num` bytes of that buffer have not changed. You can add data to the buffer beyond the first `num` bytes without impact.

Comment: So I'm clear: we can *"... you can add data to the buffer beyond the first num bytes"*, but we *cannot* increase the length in the subsequent call.

Comment: Must `buf` point to the same buffer? What if the application has reallocated the buffer in the mean time? Isn't the content starting at `buf` and `num` what counts?